# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Uri' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting below error while running my flutter App

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Uri' in type cast

Here is my code

```
var response = await http.get(imageURL as Uri);
```

I have tried running App using

Comment: You presumably added the `as Uri` cast in a misguided attempt to fix a different error ("The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'").  Type casts in Dart do *not* change the runtime type of an object; you cannot just cast a `String` to be a `Uri`.  See the linked question for the proper way to fix the original error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse String to Uri

```dart
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageURL))
```

Comment: Got below error after updating it :(

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection reset by peer

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: tried  ```flutter clean``` but still facing issue and it says

 Unhandled Exception: Connection closed before full header was received

error is pointing to previous code change:-

var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageURL));

Comment: updated http and tried flutter clean.. it worked. Thanks for your help